# my application uploads file correctly but its setup does not,c#

Tags: c#, file, uploading

i have created an application which uploads file  on a website.

while debugging through F5 my file gets properly uploaded.

but  i have created a setup for that windows application,and when i run setup and after which i try to upload files then it does not upload properly,it shows file 0 bytes...

i think there is a problem of file path..

what 2 do?
plz help.

Thanks

Comment: please provide code snippet that is uploading file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i sorted out my problem.
It was related to spaces in file path